# CapturedTypeConstructor(*) is not a subtype of RealmModel

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I have the following method that can get a new key for Realm object. I want to be able to pass the Class as parameter:

```
private fun getNextKeyForObject(myClass: Class<*>): Int {
    mRealm?.let {
        val maxId = it.where(myClass).max("id")
        if (maxId != null) {
            return it.where(myClass).max("id").toInt() + 1
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Type parameter bound for E in fun <E : RealmModel!> where(clazz: Class<E!>!): RealmQuery<E!>!
 is not satisfied: inferred type CapturedTypeConstructor(*) is not a subtype of RealmModel!
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a `generic upper bound` (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds):

```
private fun <T : RealmModel> getNextKeyForObject(myClass: Class<T>): Int {
```